# In PlayFramework with Morphia, how do I update an object?

Tags: java, playframework, morphia

Play 1.2.4
Morphia 1.2.6a

I have tried to update a record a few different ways over far too many days. I have read a couple books, reviewed nearly every comment on Play and I still cannot figure this out.???

**MODEL**:

```
@Entity
public class MyModel extends Model{
   public String fullname;
   public String email;
}
```

**ROUTES**:

```
PUT /test1/? Application.Update1(format:'json')
PUT /test2/? Application.Update2(format:'json')
PUT /test3/? Application.Update2(format:'json')
```

**CONTROLLER**:

```
public static void Update1(MyModel mydata){
}

public static void Update2(JsonObject json){
}

public static void Update3(@Valid MyModel mydata){
}
```

**SEND**:

```
PUT
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
{ "id": "4fa932fa036494e78debbc14",
  "fullname" : "test"
}
```

Calling Update1, Update2, and Update3, all report exceptions and quit.

**CALL UPDATE1:**

```
Oops: RuntimeException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception RuntimeException: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:258)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.modules.morphia.Model.create(Model.java:73)
```

**CALL UPDATE2:**

```
NullPointerException occured : null

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.ApplicationController.Update2(ApplicationController.java:49)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
```

**UPDATE 3:**

```
Oops: RuntimeException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception RuntimeException: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.data.validation.ValidationPlugin.beforeActionInvocation(ValidationPlugin.java:59)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.beforeActionInvocation(PluginCollection.java:594)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:134)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.modules.morphia.Model.create(Model.java:73)
    at play.modules.morphia.MorphiaPlugin.bind(MorphiaPlugin.java:601)
    at play.PlayPlugin.bind(PlayPlugin.java:68)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.bind(PluginCollec
```

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is more about JSON binding than a morphia problem. AFAIK, play 1.x does not support JSON automatic bind. So probably what you need is:

```
public static void Update(String myData){
   MyModel model = new Gson().fromJSON(myData, MyModel.class);
   ...
}
```

In your client side, you must send a ajax message with the name "myData":

```
$.post("the/url", {myData: {...}}, function(response){...});
```

Comment: I tried running the following curl command, but the named parameter is always null. It seems everyone/anyone can make this call but me :(  
  
`curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{ "json" : {"fullname":"Test123","enabled":true,"email":"foobar@acme.org"}}' http://localhost:9000/update4/4fa932fa036494e78debbc14/`

Comment: I changed the function to:  
  
`public static void Update4(String id, String json){...}`

The id value comes through the URL but the json value is always null.

Comment: GOT IT! The parameter must be named "body" on the controller.

Comment: Now that I have the Json data, what is the ideal way to merge the incoming model with the existing model? Seems like I need to write a lot of field-by-field code or assume the update can completely replace the existing.

Comment: I think it's better to do `MyModel model = new Gson().fromJSON(jsonStr, MyModel.class); model.save();`

Comment: What if the model has parts that are considered internal and should never be updated by the controller method?

Comment: hmm... in this case you probably will do field-by-field code, or you can isolate those part into an embedded object for easy handling

Comment: I like the embedded object idea! Thank you once again